# a cryptic-crossword-type clue

Tags: cryptic-clues

- Terrifying pawn invades half a prison
- Cooling systems contain matter for stories
- Pursue a train of thought broken by echoed shout of astonishment
- Bearcub's paw nearly has fruit
- Putting away a gent I ruined
- El Paso, per arrangement, produces a Malayan fruit
- Strip entire: pate till feet!

Letter counts:

> Terrifying pawn invades half a prison (8)
>  Cooling systems contain matter for stories (8)
>  Pursue a train of thought broken by echoed shout of astonishment (6)
>  Bearcub's paw nearly has fruit (5)
>  Putting away a gent I ruined (6)
>  El Paso, per arrangement, produces a Malayan fruit (9)
>  Strip entire: pate till feet! (4)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The individual clue answers:

> ```
>  Terrifying pawn invades half a prison (8)                            - S(HOCK)ING_ [prison = sing sing]
>  Cooling systems contain matter for stories (8)                       - AC(COUNT)S
>  Pursue a train of thought broken by echoed shout of astonishment (6) - F(OL<)LOW
>  Bearcub's paw nearly has fruit (5)                                   - _SPAWN_
>  Putting away a gent I ruined (6)                                     - EATING*
>  El Paso, per arrangement, produces a Malayan fruit (9)               - ROSEAPPLE*
>  Strip entire: pate till feet! (4)                                    - PEEL (last letters, &lit)
> ```

The overall answer:

> "Shocking accounts follow spawn eating roseapple peel" is another cryptic clue.
>  "spawn" = EGG, "accounts" = IOUS, "roseapple peel" = R_E, making the solution **`EG(R_E)G+IOUS`**.